# Scala syntax to access property of an option inline and chain "OrElse"?

Tags: scala

Sometimes I want to return the value that is a property of an object wrapped in option, but I can't do that easily with `getValue.orElse(otherValue)`.

For instance, I am mapping properties inline and I want to use a pattern like `object.get.property.orElse("")`. But the preceding doesn't compile. How can I access that property and still maintain an option-like syntax?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `map()` to achieve this. It becomes obvious once you start to think about `Option[T]` like a container of type `T` that can hold 0 or 1 element:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val optionalPerson = Some(Person("John", 29))
val name = optionalPerson map {_.name} getOrElse "?"
```

Furthermore if you have a nested structure of `Option`s:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, parent: Option[Person])
```

you can extract nested `Option` with `flatMap`:

```
val optionalPerson = Some(Person("John", 29, Some(Person("Mary", 55, None))))
val parentName = optionalPerson flatMap {_.parent} map {_.name} getOrElse "Unknown parent name"  //Mary
```

Or you can use `filter()` to turn `Some()` into `None` when value wrapped in `Some` does not satisfy some criteria:

```
val nameIfAdult = optionalPerson filter {_.age >= 18} map {_.name}
```

Comment: Well I thought'd I'd post some knowledge but I can see you took my answer to a whole new level. Sweet...

Answer (score 4):

Use `map()` to maintain the option-like pattern.

For instance you need to get the `name` property of a `field` object. But if field is actually `None`, you can return a blank string. Like this:

`field.map(_.name).getOrElse("")`

And using it in the bigger picture:

```
implicit def castDraftModel(drafts:List[Tuple2[models.ReportInstance,Option[models.Report]]]) = drafts.map{
    (field) => 
      List(Field(
        field._1.id, 
        field._1.teamId, 
        field._2.map(_.name).getOrElse(""), 
        field._1.lastModifiedRelative, 
        field._2.map(_.id).getOrElse(0L), 
        field._2.map(_.reportType).getOrElse(""), 
        field._1.referenceId, 
        field._1.referenceName( draft._2.map(_.reportType).getOrElse("") ) ))
  }.flatten.sortBy(_.id)
```